# Как дать СОЗДАТЕЛЮ-ВЛАДЕЛЬЦУ права на файлы в папке?

Tags: windows, администрирование, права

Нужно настроить права в папке `E:\users` *(это своя папка, не встроенная в ОС)*, чтобы каждый конкретный создатель подпапки имел права на файлы в ней. Дал на `E:\users` субъекту `СОЗДАТЕЛЬ-ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ` `Полный доступ`  `Для этой папки, ее подпапок и фалов`. В результате настройка сохранилась как `Только для подпапок и файлов`. Я предполагаю, что это ограничение ОС для `СОЗДАТЕЛЬ-ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ`. Хорошо, теперь пробую создать папку под конкретным пользователем *К..на*. В результате папка имеет такие права
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е. пользователь имеет права на папку, но не имеет полных прав на подпапки или файлы в ней, если их создаст кто-то другой *(член группы Администраторы, например)*.

Возможно ли настроить права так, чтобы конкретный пользователь создатель получал `Полный доступ` `Для этой папки, ее подпапок и файлов` ?

Comment: Автоматически - вряд ли. Но полный доступ означает, в том числе, что пользователь сможет сам себе дать нужные права после создания папки.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Ага, по этому варианту и пошёл..